# AVR: ASM multiplication label with 2

Tags: avr, assembly

In the example [below](http://www.avrbeginners.net/architecture/sram_flash/sram_ops.html):

```
ldi ZL, low(2*label)
ldi ZH, high(2*label)

label:
.db "Hello world", 0
lpm
```

Why multiplication label with 2 is needed? I understand that program memory is word addressed, and I guess label: it self is 16bit long(!?).

Here is quoted text from author of the example:

> "If the address is not multiplied by two and label is at byte address 0x60 (word address 0x30), Z will point at the code stored there. I hope this clarified the addressing problem. Other versions are..."

Can you clarify.

Answer (score 3):

The assembler locations are word-addressed due to the fact that AVR opcodes are 16-bit, but the index registers work with byte locations. The multiplication by 2 addresses this discrepancy.

**EDIT:**

From the [description of the `LPM` (Load Program Memory) instruction](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc0856.pdf):

> The Program memory is organized in 16-bit words while the Z-pointer is a
>   byte address. Thus, the least significant bit of the Z-pointer selects either low byte (Z<sub>LSB</sub> = 0) or high byte (Z<sub>LSB</sub> = 1).

Therefore if we want to read program memory address 5, we need to load 10 into `Z` and then read two bytes.

Comment: I am still unable to understand.

Comment: Well then don't accept it until you do...

Comment: "Thus, the least significant bit of the Z-pointer selects either low byte (ZLSB = 0) or high byte (ZLSB = 1)."

Ah now i get it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Zippi - now you can accept this answer. :)

Comment: @johnfound Well i guess i can now :)